# User redirected to homepage after deleting a product in "view cart"

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax

User redirected to homepage after deleting a product in "view cart". When I add the item to cart it remains in same page, but when I remove the item from cart it redirects to home page. How to fix this issue?
My remove function look like below:

```
     public function removeAction()

     {


    $cart   = $this->_getCart();

    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        /**
         * Check product availability
         */

        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $items = $cart->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $id) {
            if( $item->getQty() == 1 ){
                $cart->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
            }
            else if($item->getQty() > 1){
                $item->setQty($item->getQty() - 1);
                $cart->save();
            }
            break;
            }
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                //$message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                //$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
           $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `_redirectReferer()` method at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`, calls `_getRefererUrl()` method and it verify the param "uenc" passed via GET checking if come from store, per bases url (secure & unsecure). This param (uenc) is an URI encoded, so if you use something like varnish that changes URI (with :8080 for example), your URI looks like different than expected. If URI is not an internal URI, Magento redirects user to your homepage (base_url).

Try put some logs in `_getRefererUrl()` method to see if URI is changed.

Answer (score 2):

I gather there are no entries in the error logs? (system or exception) ?

Not a solution, but a guide in solving your issue.

This would best be solved using a debugger with breakpoints (xdebug + IDE) and stepping through your code until you find the line that is causing the redirect.

It could be anything, from an exception, to the _goBack() routine not having the required information set to allow the code flow to correctly GoBack to the correct page. I would thus also whack a breakpoint in the goBack method (located in Mage_Checkout_CartController) and see what happens (if) your flow enters that routine.

This type of issue is easily solved if you have a development environment with proper debugging tools. without that you will really just be taking pot-shots in the dark as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting an item the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirectReferer` method is called. It looks for a referer url and checks if the found url is an internal url.

```
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

If it is not or the referer is empty, the base url will be used for redirection.

Maybe this is a good starting point for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by following steps.

Navigate to `"app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php".`

Find "`deleteAction()`" function and the function will look like bellow.

```
 public function deleteAction()
     {
         $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
         if ($id) {
             try {
                 $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                   ->save();
             } catch (Exception $e) {
                 $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                 Mage::logException($e);
             }
         }
         $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
     }
```

You need to change the line `"$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));"` to `$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');`. So now the function will look like below.

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                  ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
```

The above is not a proffered way to do that. I just explained the place to debug. Try to [create a module](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/) and override the above function. That's the proffered way.

For more information refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499720/3049065).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me you are over-complicating things here by creating your own action. Could you not simply use the `Mage_Checkout_CartController::updatePostAction`. With this action you are able to do the following.

1. Empty cart,
2. Update quantity,

Have a look into the functions `_updateShoppingCart` and `_emptyShoppingCart` for how this actually works but the default code should do mostly what you need.